# distorted video

Tags: video, youtube

When viewing youtube videos, video is distorted like this:

[image: distorted video screenshot]

Flash player is up to date, javascript is enabled, and same issue for firefox and chromium browsers. What to do?

Comment: Audio plays fine.

Comment: This looks like either a graphics card issue or a driver issue; does this happen in Windows as well? Have you tried changing the video-drivers?